# Sending env variables from docker-compose to codeigniter app

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, codeigniter-4

I have a CodeIgniter 4 application that works fine locally, but the server where it should be hosted has an old version of PHP and MariaDB (5.6, 10.1.41).

My idea is to create a container that connects to the production database, but I am having trouble passing the environment variables from Docker to CodeIgniter.

So far, I have the following:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: test
    build:
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    environment:
      CI_ENVIRONMENT: development
  mariadb:
    image: "mariadb:10.1.41"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: "root"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ""
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ""
      LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
      LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"
      LANGUAGE: "en_US.UTF-8"
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/ico/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    command: ["mysqld", "--log-bin", "--max-allowed-packet=500M"]
    restart: always
```

I also tried the following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: test
    build:
      context: ./
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
    environment:
      CI_ENVIRONMENT: development
      DATABASE_HOSTNAME: host.docker.internal
      DATABASE_USERNAME: root
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ''
      DATABASE_NAME: test
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
ARG MYSQL_USER
ARG MYSQL_PASSWORD
ARG MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
ARG MYSQL_DATABASE

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQL_DATABASE MYSQL_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD MYSQL_USER=$MYSQL_USER

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y && \
    apt-get install -y curl && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev && \
    apt-get install -y libicu-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install intl mysqli


COPY sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
COPY . /var/www/html/


RUN apt-get update
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN chown 777 -R /var/www/html/ \
    && chown 777 -R  /var/www/html/public \
    && chown 777 -R  /var/www/html/writable


RUN service apache2 restart
```

I have tried to set the environment variables in the environment section of the web service, but CodeIgniter does not process them.

I get the following error:

```
CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException #8

Unable to connect to the database.
```

If I check the $_SERVER envs, I can see the default from the env file, but not the ones from docker

Do you know how I can pass the environment variables from Docker Compose to CodeIgniter?

Thank you!

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Including your PHP source code where you try to access the environment variables would also make your question easier to answer.

Comment: You don't seem to actually be setting the environment variables in the Compose file for the `web` service; I'd put them in the `environment:` block there, and remove the `ARG` and `ENV` lines from the Dockerfile.  (The last two `RUN` lines seem like they're unnecessary and potentially dangerous, and I'd remove those too.)

Comment: I did that, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

## Dynamically creating env files (any CI Version)

You can make a run.sh script that checks if the .env file exists, if so, it deletes it and creates a new one mapping the CI variables to the container's environment variables.

```
if [ -f /tmp/.env ]
then
    rm /tmp/.env
fi

touch /tmp/.env
echo "CI_ENVIRONMENT = ${CI_ENVIRONMENT}" >> /tmp/.env
echo "database.default.hostname = ${DATABASE_HOSTNAME}" >> /tmp/.env
echo "database.default.username = ${DATABASE_USERNAME}" >> /tmp/.env
echo "database.default.password = ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}" >> /tmp/.env

php spark serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Remember to change the index.php file to read .env from the tmp directory:

```
// Load environment settings from .env files into $_SERVER and $_ENV
require_once SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/DotEnv.php';
(new CodeIgniter\Config\DotEnv('/tmp'))->load();
```

## Map variables into the config files (any CI Version)

The .env files are just a way to super seed default values inside the config files. It is possible to change the config construct method to make the config variables be the container's environment variables. Bellow, the file app/Config/App.php is updated to have a __construct method that make the baseURL property have the environment value.

```
...
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->baseURL = getenv('app_baseURL');
    }
...
```

## Automatic mapping (CI >= 4.1.5)

According to the docs (I use this functionality) you can define the same environment variables as inside the .env file but using "_" instead of "." on the variable names. As an example, if I want to define a container environment variable that maps to app.BaseURL I just define app_baseURL. This functionality is defined in the [user guide](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/configuration.html#namespace-separator).